# Custom view single content wrapper css style

Tags: views, theming

My custom view which shows only two rows of data looks like this

- content1
- content2

but I want to display them side by side like this 
content1  content2

to do this I have to apply float left and width 50% to the content wrapper css class or id 
but the problem it has a long **views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first** css class how do I modify this class ?

```
<div class="view-content">
    <div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first">
    </div>

    <div class="views-row views-row-2 views-row-even views-row-last">
    </div>
</div>
```

Result I need is

```
<div class="view-content">
    <div class="customeview">
    </div>

    <div class="customeview">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reduce the standard markup with these options in views:

[image: In Views -> Format / Show / Fields / Settings]

[image: In Views -> Field - Settings / Style Settings]

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to Volker's answer, I'd like to precise that these available options in Views 3 were previously in a contributed module called [Semantic Views](http://drupal.org/project/semanticviews). This module has been integrated into Drupal 7, but not all of its features, so it is not totally obsolete for Drupal 7 (see [this thread](http://drupal.org/node/1013876) for more info).